# Passing string arguments implicitly

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass string arguments implicitly in JavaScript?

I made a working version:

```
function fullName (firstName, lastName) {

return firstName + " " + lastName

}

fullName ("John", "Doe");
```

Is it possible to provide first name and last name parameters without “” in JavaScript? I tried to enter just `fullName (John, Doe);` and I got an error.

Thank you.

Comment: only if there are variables called `John` and `Doe` representing those strings. Otherwise the answer is _no_.

Comment: Yes. You can use `'` instead of `"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`"John"` is a string literal. `John` is a variable name.

Some programming languages will treat an unknown variable as having a default value of a string equivalent to the name, but JavaScript isn't one of them.

(Well, the languages I know about which do that use `$` to indicate variables, so it is unknown constants they treat that way, but the point holds.)